# How to solve font problem in exam class

Tags: exam

I have noticed something strange when I change font style in exam class.
Using default font the MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,xetex,12pt]{exam}
 \usepackage{mathspec} 
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
 \begin{document} 
\setlength\dottedlinefillheight{1cm}
 \begin{questions}
 \question
Explain what is meant by the term \textbf{mole fraction} \fillwithdottedlines{3cm} 
\end{questions} 
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Now changing the font by uncommenting the line %\setmainfont{Times New Roman} I get this

[image]

As you can see the answer lines reduced from 3 to 2 and there is a wide gap shown by the double headed arrow.
I sincerely ask for help from the community to sort me out from this mess.

Comment: This is something to do (I think) with the size of glyphs of the font. If you change the`\setlength\dottedlinefillheight{1cm}` to `\setlength\dottedlinefillheight{0.95cm}` you get 3 lines without the gap.

Comment: Very helpful comment @MiltosP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we add `\showoutput`, we see when the font is the default,

```
.....\cleaders 0.0 plus 1.0fill
......\hbox(1.164+0.0)x5.28003, glue set 1.00801fil
.......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.......\TU/lmr/m/n/12 .
.......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
```

which refers to the leaders of `\dotfill`.

When Times New Roman is used, we see instead,

```
.....\cleaders 0.0 plus 1.0fill
......\hbox(1.13672+0.16405)x5.28003, glue set 1.14001fil
.......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.......\TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n/12 .
.......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
```

Do you see the difference? The box has a depth which it hasn't with the default Latin Modern font. A tiny difference, but that doesn't allow the vertical leaders to use three copies of the dotted rules, because they would exceed the specified height of 3cm by precisely 0.49215pt.

You can fix this by patching `\dotfill` to use a smashed period.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\xpatchcmd{\dotfill}{\hss.\hss}{\hss\smash{.}\hss}{}{}

\begin{document}

\setlength\dottedlinefillheight{1cm}

\begin{questions}
\question
Explain what is meant by the term \textbf{mole fraction} \fillwithdottedlines{3cm}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Avoid passing the document class option `xetex`. It does nothing good.

A possibly better definition for `\do@fillwithdottedlines` that you may suggest to the maintainer of `exam.cls`.

The idea is to replace the `\vrule` bits with a `\vbox` to the specified height, killing the possible depth of the periods.

```
\def\do@fillwithdottedlines#1{%
  \begingroup
  \ifhmode
    \par
  \fi
  \hrule height \z@
  \nobreak
  \setbox0=\vbox to \dottedlinefillheight{%
    \vss
    \hbox to \hsize{%
      \hskip \@totalleftmargin
      \dotfill
    }%
    \vskip-\prevdepth % kill the depth of the dots
  }%
  % We use \cleaders (rather than \leaders) so that a given
  % vertical space will always produce the same number of lines
  % no matter where on the page it happens to start:
  \cleaders \copy0 \vskip #1 \hbox{}%
  \endgroup
}% \do@fillwithdottedlines
```

Remember to use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` if you adopt this code.

Comment: Thanks @egreg for your kind advice on the usage of xetex

Comment: @Kidegalize I added a different solution, which I'd prefer `exam` would adopt.